# Function returns wrong value if I don't print char array

Tags: c, beagleboneblack

I have a very strange situation. I have two functions that I am using to read values of the analog inputs of a Beagle Bone Black. The first function opens the file and reads the pin value and SHOULD return it to another function that is comparing that value to the value of another pin. Everything works as it should only when I print the `BUFFER` that I am using to concatenate the pin number with the file path. As soon as I comment out the line, I am getting bad values. How can simply printing or not printing the `BUFFER` cause this?

```
float AIN_value(char AIN) {
    float value;
    char line[10] = {0};
    char BUFFER[150];
    sprintf(BUFFER, "%s%c", AIN_FILE, AIN);
    FILE *fp;
    //printf("%s\n", BUFFER);
    fp  = fopen(BUFFER, "r");
    if (! is_open(fp)) {
        printf("ERROR: could not open %s\n", BUFFER);
        exit(1);
    }
    fgets(line, sizeof(line), fp);
    value = atoi(line);
    fclose(fp);
    //printf("%d\n", value);
    return(value);
}

bool pins_within_threshold(photores *data) {
    float P0_value = AIN_value(data->AP_0);
    float P1_value = AIN_value(data->AP_1);
    float highest_pin_value;
    float lowest_pin_value;
    if (P0_value > P1_value) {
        highest_pin_value = P0_value;
        lowest_pin_value = P1_value;
    }
    else if (P1_value > P0_value) {
        highest_pin_value = P1_value;
        lowest_pin_value = P0_value;
    }
    else if (P0_value == P1_value){
        return(true);
    }

    float numerator = highest_pin_value - lowest_pin_value;
    float denominator = (highest_pin_value + lowest_pin_value) / 2;
    float quotient = numerator/denominator;
    float threshold = quotient * 100;
    printf("P0_value: %f\n", P0_value);
    printf("P1_value: %f\n", P1_value);
    printf("Threshold: %f%%\n", threshold);
    if (threshold <= data->move_threshold) {
        return(true);
    }
    else if (threshold > data->move_threshold) {
        return(false);
    }`enter code here`
    else {
        return(true);
    }
}
```

EDIT:
By 'good' values I mean that `bool pins_within_threshold(photores *data)` will print the correct threshold. This 'threshold' is the percent difference of the values of two photoresistors. They are both getting equal amounts of light and the threshold will generally be within a 5% difference. The threshold will be a correct output only when I print the BUFFER in `float AIN_value(char AIN)`. When the printf is commented out,  `bool pins_within_threshold(photores *data)` is printing that the pins are not within the threshold and that one pin gets no reading at all. I consider this a 'bad' value.

EDIT 2:
Here is the output after commenting out `snprintf(BUFFER, sizeof(BUFFER), "%s%c", AIN_FILE, AIN)`:

```
AIN5: 1696
AIN6: 0
Threshold: 200.000000%
```

Here is the output if I print:

```
AIN5: 1366
AIN6: 1379
Threshold: 0.947522%
```

EDIT 3:
After some time chatting with chux, It is clear that there is a file read sync issue because the OS owns the file and the file is in a constant state of change. For some reason, a simple `printf('\n'); fixes the problem. Not a complete fix, would like a better understand as to why this happens and how I an avoid it.

Comment: "I am getting bad values". How do you know? What do they look like? Complete gibberish, bits shifted by one, bytes reversed... can you be more specific? And presumably the file was opened correctly? And the line that you are commenting out - is it `printf("%s\n", BUFFER);`? What happens if you print something else (not `BUFFER` - maybe `strlen(BUFFER)` or something else)?

Comment: @Floris I have no ABSOLUTE way of knowing without printing it, but seeing that I get the correct output if I don't print `BUFFER` but good ones if I do, I assumed. `strlen(BUFFER)` does cause the program to work properly. Once I comment it out, it goes bad again.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "Good" and "bad" values? Could you please provide some output example?

Comment: @Subzero please see my edit in the OP.

Comment: Minor: Change `else if (P0_value == P1_value){` to `else {` to catch `float` values that are not comparable (NaN).

Comment: Minor: `fgets(line, sizeof(line), fp)` _could_ return NULL (read error) and `line` is in an unknown state.

Comment: @chux `sprintf(BUFFER, "%148s%c", AIN_FILE, AIN);` introduces space before my string in `BUFFER` which holds a file path, and now getting path error.

Comment: @arynhard face palm!  Should have said `snprintf(BUFFER, sizeof(BUFFER), "%s%c", AIN_FILE, AIN)`.

Comment: @chux this is actually a better way to concatenate my string, but please see my second edit. I just don't understand why or how this happens.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39958/discussion-between-chux-and-arynhard)

Comment: 1) Consider reducing your loop rate, allowing the dynamically create voltage values more time to generate. 2) Maybe you should not open as a file, but as a pipe and use popen().

Comment: @chux `popen` using something like `cat`? I thought popen was to run os type commands?

Comment: Something like http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Creating-a-Pipe.html

Answer (score 1):

You are using atoi in the line:

```
value = atoi(line);
```

That converts the char* line to an int (i.e. "value" gets stored as an integer). But you defined "value" as a "float" and you intend to return it as "float". Converting it into an int using "atoi" will make you truncate values (e.g. atoi() will stop reading from str as soon as a non-numerical character has been read. ).
You should use atof() instead- i.e. convert the above line to-

value = atof(line);

```
#include <stdlib.h>
int atoi( const char *str );
```

Description:
The atoi() function converts str into an integer, and returns that integer. str should start with some sort of number, and atoi() will stop reading from str as soon as a non-numerical character has been read.

Example:
i = atoi( "512.035" );

RESULT: i set to 512.

Comment: Also, you should use %f format specifier to print the float "value".

Comment: Tried but same thing is happening. Thank you for that catch though, my original intent was an int and forget to change this.

Answer (score 0):

Reading an AIN value can cause the ADC to trigger another conversion. So it is the delay in printf that is the cause of the good values.  Replace the printf with usleep(1000).
There is a kernel patch here that may help:
http://beagleboard-gsoc13.blogspot.ca/2013/07/sampling-analogue-signals-using-adc-on.html